# Change multiple values with ifelse in tidyverse

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I hav a dataset with 20.000 Observations and 5 Variables. Now I want to change in some specific observations only one variable. I know that I can do this for every row like this:

```
test_data <- test_data%>%
  mutate(change_variable=ifelse(n=="1000","changevalue",changevariable))
```

My problem is now that I need to change 500 Obersvations like this. Is there any possibility to automate this process instead of writing a code of 500 lines? It is every time the same variable to get changed and I have the right value for this variable in a dataframe connected to the right "n" value.

I Hope someone of you can help me with this.

Kind Regards,
Tom

Comment: As @akrun mentioned you should post a reproducible example. It's not clear from your question what the logic is for changing the value in your column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be a "join" (merge) operation.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)
mt <- sample_n(mtcars, 6)
mt
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Toyota Corona      21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# Valiant            18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
# Ferrari Dino       19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# Merc 240D          24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Chrysler Imperial  14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
newgears <- data.frame(gear = c(2, 3, 4), newgear = c(22, 33, 44))
newgears
#   gear newgear
# 1    2      22
# 2    3      33
# 3    4      44
```

The premise is that you have one frame that has a mapping from the original values (`gear`) to a new value (`newgear`). Not all existing `gear` values need to be present in `newgears` (we handle that), nor is there a problem if there are extra `gear` values in this new frame, as they will be ignored.

With this,

```r
left_join(mt, newgears, by = "gear")
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb newgear
# 1 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1      33
# 2 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4      33
# 3 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1      33
# 4 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6      NA
# 5 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2      44
# 6 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4      33
```

From this, notice that we have one `gear` value that was not mapped to a `newgear`. This can be expected and normal, we just need to account for it. In our case, we will `coalesce` first `newgear` then `gear`; what this does is use `newgear` unless it is `NA`, in which case use `gear` instead.

```r
left_join(mt, newgears, by = "gear") %>%
  mutate(gear = coalesce(newgear, gear)) %>%
  select(-newgear)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0   33    1
# 2 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0   33    4
# 3 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0   33    1
# 4 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# 5 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0   44    2
# 6 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0   33    4
```

I believe the use of a mapping frame (`newgears` here) is easier to maintain and visualize, not to mention code and use in a multitude of ways and places.

Comment: Sorry guys I´m new here and I think because of that it´s difficult to me to describe my problem in a good way. 

This solution works out for me. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If we need to change only for specific observation, create the logical expression with `row_number()` and `%in%`.  If the "changevalue" are specific for first 500 observation, create it as a column

```
library(dplyr)
test_data$changevalue[1:500] <- vector_of_values
test_data <- test_data %>%
   mutate(change_variable = ifelse(
         row_number() %in% 1:500, changevalue, changevariable))
```

Or this can be done with `coalesce` as well

```
test_data %>%
    mutate(change_variable = coalesce(changevalue, changevariable))
```

Or can use `between`

```
test_data %>%
   mutate(change_variable = ifelse(between(row_number(), 1, 500),
        changevalue, changevariable))
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I need to make it more clear. I have some data of 500 observations with 500 different values in a dataframe. With this approach I would give every observation the same value isn´t it?
But I need to give every specific row his specific "changevalue"

Comment: @Sylababa I request you to update your post with a small reproducible example and expected output so that it becomes more clear.  Your comment is not clear to me.  If there are specifi changevalue, why can't you create a column of 'changevalue' in the data and use `ifelse` as in here after changing the 'changevlaue' to `changevalue` column

Comment: a way to deal with this to split your dataframe in a part with no corrections and the for which the corrections are needed (ie. your 500 rows). Then simply create a vector of length 500 which comprises the values you need to replace/overwrite. After the correction you can combine the data frames again. If you need to ensure the sequence, the assign row_number() to a column before splitting. After the bind_rows, you can then sort by this column to have the old "order".

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a test vector inside of a base R `ifelse` statement.  Each test will use the row index number of the test vector.  E.g.

Generate a test vector for `cars$cyl` (cars = mtcars) and test it against each `cars$cyl` entry.  Assign the test result to `cars$test` to check.

```
cars <- mtcars
testvec <- sample(c(4, 6, 8), 32, replace = TRUE)
cars$test <- ifelse(cars$cyl == testvec, 'match', 'no match')
cars <- cbind(cars, testvec)
head(cars, 10)
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     test testvec
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 no match       8
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 no match       8
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    match       4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 no match       4
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 no match       4
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 no match       4
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4    match       8
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 no match       6
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 no match       8
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 no match       8
```